# How to use Optimizely.dispatchEvents() method from Optimizely Android SDK

Tags: android, optimizely

The quickstart guide for the Optimizely Android SDK includes the following example:

```
private void userClickedImportantButton() {
      Optimizely.trackEvent("ImportantButtonClicked");
      Optimizely.dispatchEvents(); // Manually send the event logs back to the server
  }
```

This can be found [here](http://developers.optimizely.com/android/#network-settings)

However, the example is incorrect and doesn't actually work - it appears that `dispatchEvents()` is an instance method, not static method, of the `Optimizely` class.

What is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Optimizely folks answered my question on their community forum post:

https://community.optimizely.com/t5/Mobile-Apps/Android-how-to-use-Optimizely-dispatchEvents/m-p/10907#M121

The answer is that `dispatchEvents()` is deprecated and you should use `sendEvents()` instead.